# Checking Whether a String Contains a Set of Characters the order is important

Tags: python

Sarah has just learned to type and go online. As soon as he entered the internet, he decided to enter a chat room and greet everyone. Sarah entered a word in the chat room. If it is possible to delete some letters of the word that Sarah entered and the word hello remains at the end, it means that Sara could say hello otherwise.
It is guaranteed that the input consists only of lowercase English letters.
I try this

input ahhellllloou
output  YES
input hlelo
output NO

```
def isany(str,list):
    for c in list:
        if c in str:
            return "yes"
        
    return "no"

List=['h','e','l','l','o']
Str='hlelo'
print(isany(Str,List))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please, could you write the expected output?

Comment: You can get the index (say `idx`)of the first character and for the second character you can try to get the index of that character in the substring `str[idx + 1:]`. Do this in a loop every time replacing `idx`

Comment: If the length of the string is N, it work work in order O(N^2). It would be more efficient to use an array of bools of length 27, run on the string, if the Nth bool is false print the letter and set to true, otherwise skip the letter. It would work in order of O(N), trading run time for memory.

Comment: @kuro can you please explain more

Comment: @UriRaz please explain more I'm new to codeing

Comment: @UriRaz, how will that work? In think OP also needs to check the order. @omid, you can use the `index()` or `find()` of string to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below code -

```
def isany(st, lst):
    last_idx = 0

    for c in lst:
        idx = st[last_idx:].find(c) # find the character in the sub string
        if -1 == idx:                  # character not found
            return "no"
        last_idx += idx + 1

    return "yes"
```

Now for example take the input `hlelo`.

- In the first iteration, `c` holds value `'h'`. So, the substring becomes `st[0:]` (as `last_index` was 0) which means the whole string. We find `'h'` in that string and got back index 0. So, we update `last_index` as 1, because we should search from index 1 in the next iteration.
- In the next iteration, the substring (i.e. `st[last_index:]`) becomes `st[1:]` or `"lelo"`. We find `'e'` in that and got `idx` as 1. Keep in mind that here `idx` represents the index of the substring (i.e. `"lelo"`) and not the input string (i.e. `"hlelo"`). So the next index we should search from is `idx` + 1 after the `last_index`.

The code runs until the loop exits or the `idx` becomes -1 when the character is not found and returns result appropriately

Comment: `input` is a built-in python function which you would be overwriting in the scope of that function

Comment: @TomMcLean, right. changed the name `input`